# retriving a document by its DocId in Documents List Data API

Tags: google-api, google-docs-api, google-docs

I'm trying to retrieve a document by id, to get the folders/Collections that have associated this document, but am getting this error

com.google.gdata.util.ParseException: [Line 1, Column 266] Invalid root element, expected (namespace uri:local name)

this is the code:

```
  DocsService client = new DocsService("test testnet v1");
  URL feedUri = new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/"+DOCID+"?oauth_token="+token);
DocumentListFeed feed = client.getFeed(feedUri, DocumentListFeed.class);
      for (DocumentListEntry entry : feed.getEntries()) {
          if (!entry.getParentLinks().isEmpty()) {
                for (Link link : entry.getParentLinks()) {
                      System.out.print(link.getTitle()+""+link.getHref());                      
                          }
              }
      }
```

do not know if this is the best way, or which is the way to get a document by its id

Answer (score 0):

Can you send you request using [OAuth Playground](https://code.google.com/oauthplayground) to look at the raw XML data and share it with us?
There might be an invalid XML element that prevents the parser to parse it.